# Draw image in another image doesn't work on iOS device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I need your help to draw an image in another image on iOS. For this moment, I use the code below:

```
UIImage* finalimage = [self drawImage:ECAImage inImage:finalimage atPoint:ECALocation];
```

My function:

```
-(UIImage*) drawImage:(UIImage*) fgImage inImage:(UIImage*) bgImage atPoint:(CGPoint)  point
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bgImage.size, FALSE, 0.0);
    [bgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, bgImage.size.width, bgImage.size.height)];
    [fgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( point.x, point.y, fgImage.size.width, fgImage.size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This code works on iPhone 5.0 simulator but not on my device iPhone 5.0.1.
I can display the bgImage but the fgImage is not drawing. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your foreground image is loading.  I've had problems with the sim, because it is only case sensitive if the underlying file system is case sensitive, so for most people, it is tolerant of case mismatches in file names, whereas the devices are always case sensitive.

[aside]
I now run one a case sensitive file system.  This gave me massive problems submitting to the app store, but that is another story...